# A numerical method is proven to be 1st-order accurate for $u' = F(u)$ and $u' = G(u)$. Also for $u' = F(u)+G(u)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

A numerical method is proven to be 1st-order accurate for $u' = F(u)$ and $u' = G(u)$, $t \in (0,T]$. Let $u_{F}(t)$ and $u_{G}(t)$ be the exact solutions of the two equations respectively. Let $v_{F}(t), \:\: v_{G}(t)$ be the numerical solutions respectively. Let $|w_{F}(t)|, \:\: |w_{G}(t)|$ be the error respectively. 1st-order accurate means there are constants $K_{F},K_{G} > 0$ such that

$$ |w_{F}| \le K_{F} \triangle t, \:\:\:\: |w_{G}| \le K_{G} \triangle t, \:\:\:\: \text{as} \:\: \triangle t \rightarrow 0$$

for all $t \in [0, T]$.

Does this imply the ODE $u' = F(u) + G(u)$ is also 1st-order accurate?

If not, what are some proper or clever ways to analyze this?

Comment: So the method an its error order can depend on the ODE to be solved? How are the methods compose to make the method for the last equation?

Comment: If $F$ and $G$ are linear, sure, but in general, no, I would not expect it. The problem is that $u_F$ and $u_G$ could be quite large, putting $F(u_F + u_G)$ in an region where $F$ behaves much differently than it does about $F(u_F)$ and similarly for $G$.